# Appstore Preview link display connecting on browser

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store, app-store-connect

[image]

While opening the iOS app store link in a browser I am redirected to the mac app store app and the browser displayed only connecting text instead of displaying application information. It would be beneficial if anyone could guide me on this, and where I can make the change.

Note: The app is available on the app store and the app store account also is working

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue that the Support Destination Option (Mac) was missing in the Xcode that's why the information of the app was not displayed in the browser.

[image]